# Compare two ints from same class, in a different class

Tags: java, arrays, class, if-statement

Doing a big assignment for school and need help with a problem.

We need to compare two ints from "Class X" (Attribute class), in "Class Y" where we have some methods. This is just the structure of the assignment.

Our code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Event {

private String name;
private int numberOfTries;
private ArrayList<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<Result>();

public Event(String name, int numberOfTries) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numberOfTries = numberOfTries;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getNumberOfTries() {
    return numberOfTries;
}

public String toString() {
    return name + ", " + numberOfTries;
}

public void addResult(Participant partResult) {
    int participantIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
        if (resultList.get(i).getParticipant().getStartNumber() == partResult.getStartNumber()) {
    for (int a = 0; a < result.length; a++)
    result[i] = maxAttempts();
}
}
}
}
```

Problem with this: result can not be solved to a variable. maxAttempts is undefined for the type Event.

Other class:

```
public class Result {

public double[] result;
public Participant participant;
public int maxAttempts;
public int attemptsUsed;
public Result(double result, int noOfAttempts, Participant p) {
    //this.result = result;
    this.result = new double[noOfAttempts];
    this.result[0]= result;
    this.participant = p;
    this.maxAttempts=noOfAttempts;
    attemptsUsed++;
    }

public double[] getResult() {
    return result;
}
public Participant getParticipant() {
    return participant;
}
public int getAttemptsUsed() {
    return attemptsUsed;
}
public int getMaxAttempts() {
    return maxAttempts;
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SportsCompetition {
private Scanner scan;
private ArrayList<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
private ArrayList<Participant> participantList = new   ArrayList<Participant>();
private int eventLoop, participantLoop, participantLoop2, participantLoop3,  number, startNumber;
private Participant partResult;
private Event eventResult;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SportsCompetition().run();
}

private void run() {
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    commandLoop();
}

private void commandLoop() {
    boolean exit = false;
    do {
        System.out.println(
                "Vad vill du göra?\n1. Lägg till gren\n2. Lägg till deltagare\n3. Ta bort deltagare\n4. Lägg till resultat\n5. Resultatlista för deltagare\n6. Resultatlista för gren\n7. Meddelande\n8. Avsluta");
        String Command = scan.nextLine();
        switch (Command) {
        case "1":
        case "add event":
            addEvent();
            break;
        case "2":
        case "add participant":
            addParticipant();
            break;
        case "3":
        case "remove participant":
            removeParticipant();
            break;
        case "4":
        case "add result":
            addResult();
            break;
        //
        // case "5":
        // case "participant":
        // participant();
        // break;
        //
        // case "6":
        // case "GRENNAMN":
        // OKLART();
        // break;
        //
        // case "7":
        // case "message":
        // message();
        // break;
        //
        case "8":
        case "exit":
            exit = true;
        default:
            System.out.println("Fel! Mata in godkänt kommando!");
        }
    } while (!exit);
}

public void addEvent() {
    eventList.add(new Event("Jacob", 5));
    eventLoop = 0;
    while (eventLoop == 0) {
        eventLoop++;
        System.out.print("Event name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        name = name.trim();
        if (name.matches(".*[a-z].*")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
                if (eventList.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {
                    System.out.println("Error " + name + " has already been added\n");
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: name can't be empty!");
            eventLoop = 0;
        }
        System.out.print("Attempts allowed: ");
        int numberOfTries = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        while (numberOfTries <= 0) {
            System.out.print("Error: too low, must be at least one attempt: ");
            int numberOfTries2 = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            numberOfTries = numberOfTries;
        }
        eventList.add(new Event(name, numberOfTries));
        System.out.println(name + " added\n");

    }
}

public boolean checkString(String s) {
    if (s.length() > 0 && s.matches(".*[a-z].*")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addParticipant() {
    String firstName = "name";
    String lastName = "name";
    String team = "name";
    participantLoop = 0;
    while (participantLoop == 0) {
        System.out.print("First name: ");
        firstName = scan.nextLine();
        firstName = firstName.trim();
        if (checkString(firstName) == false) {
            System.out.println("Error: name can't be empty!");
            participantLoop = 0;
        } else {
            participantLoop++;
        }
    }
    participantLoop2 = 0;
    while (participantLoop2 == 0) {
        System.out.print("Last name: ");
        lastName = scan.nextLine();
        lastName = lastName.trim();
        if (checkString(lastName) == false) {
            System.out.println("Error: name can't be empty!");
            participantLoop2 = 0;
        } else {
            participantLoop2++;
        }
    }
    participantLoop3 = 0;
    while (participantLoop3 == 0) {
        participantLoop3++;
        System.out.print("Team: ");
        team = scan.nextLine();
        team = team.trim();
        if (checkString(team) == false) {
            System.out.println("Error: name can't be empty!");
            participantLoop3 = 0;
        } else {
            // boolean found = false;
            // for (int i = 0; i < participantList.size(); i++) {
            // if (participantList.get(i).getTeam().equalsIgnoreCase(team)) {
            // participantList.get(i);
            // found = true;
            // }
            // }
            //
            // if (!found) {
            // participantList.add(new Team);
            // }
            participantLoop3++;
        }
    }
    number++;
    startNumber = 99 + number;
    participantList.add(new Participant(firstName, lastName, team, startNumber));
    System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " from " + team + " with number " + startNumber + " added.");
    // printa listan för att testa
    System.out.print(participantList);
}

public void removeParticipant() {
    System.out.println("Skriv in siffran på deltagaren du vill ta bort: ");
    int startNumber = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < participantList.size(); i++) {
        if (participantList.get(i).getStartNumber() == startNumber) {
            participantList.remove(i);
            found = true;
            System.out.println(startNumber + " har tagits bort!\n");
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("Error: no participant with number" + startNumber + "found!\n");
    }
}

public void addResult() {

    System.out.println("Ange nummer på deltagare: ");
    int startNumber = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    boolean numberFound = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < participantList.size(); i++) {
        if (participantList.get(i).getStartNumber() == startNumber) {
            numberFound = true;
            partResult = participantList.get(i);
        }
    }
    if (!numberFound) {
        System.out.println("Error: no participant with number " + startNumber + " found!\n");
        numberFound = false;
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Event: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    boolean eventFound = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
        if (eventList.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            eventFound = true;
            eventResult = eventList.get(i);
        }
    }

    if (!eventFound) {
        System.out.println("Error: no event with name " + name + " found!\n");
        eventFound = false;
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Results for " + partResult.getFirstName() + " " + partResult.getLastName() + " from "
            + partResult.getTeam() + " in " + eventResult.getName() + ": ");
    int result = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

}
}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Participant {

private String firstName, lastName, team;
private int startNumber;
private ArrayList<Result> participantResultList = new ArrayList<Result>();

public Participant(String firstName, String lastName, String team, int startNumber) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.team = team;
    this.startNumber = startNumber;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getTeam() {
    return team;
}

public int getStartNumber() {
    return startNumber;
}

public String toString() {
    return firstName + lastName + team + startNumber;
}

public void addResult(Result result) {
    participantResultList.add(result);
}

}
```

Comment: I assume you've heard of getters and setters? what error do you get?

Comment: Here we are stuck. We want to check if X<Y, as long as X<Y we want to add X to an array. When X>Y, we want to stop and send error message to user. The problem is that X and Y is in a different class than this method. We can't seem to point to those attributes. The code is not compiling.******

Comment: there is no X and no Y in your code. don't give something that "looks like the error", give the actual error

Comment: declare the variables public then create getter, setter for the declared variables. So you can get the variable's/method's value in any other class you want by getter method.

Comment: @Zakan you have to at least show the relevant code. with the bit you've posted so far, there's nothing we can tell.

Comment: @Zakan slow down and please give the exact error message and the exact code that belongs to it by editing the question. (And not as comments)

Comment: Zakan, please briefly scan over [ask] and [mcve], then edit your question to provide the latter. This way, people will actually be able to help.

Comment: so, there are no elements in your ResultList, that means you can't get any information out of it.

Comment: what line is it that throws the exception, and what is the exact error message?

Comment: @Zakan he's just informing you of the rules of SO. so far, you've (still) posted very little information to go on, and what I've seen from your code so far, doesn't make all that much sense. In your original post, it seemed that the getStartNumber() calls gave the problem. Seeing as that code will never run, delete it, and you're good. if you need it, you'll need to show your Participant code as well.

Comment: @Zakan in this class, there are no elements added to ResultList. If the problem is in the main method, why don't you show that? Without knowing the code we should be looking at, there's nothing we can do

Comment: I apologize! ALL the code is up now.

Comment: Just go and read and **apply** [mcve] to your posting. And please delete all the comments that are no longer required. And hint: the next time you enter a new community, check their rules and policies **before** putting up a post.

Comment: And to all of the folks: 22 comments, but only one close request?!

Comment: @GhostCat New to programming and everything. Did not realize the size of this question. ye ye, I'll do better.

Comment: Overall, this question is a nice example how things should **not** be done. This community is not a free tutor service where people **work** with you through your problems. So coming in with an unclear question ... exactly causes what we see here: various other newbies dropping "code only" answers that (as you noticed yourself) ... often don't help at all, but lead to other errors. Please understand that this is not "programming school". The idea is that you provide a clear, crisp question (as outlined by [mcve] for example) - that actually has a good chance of being answered.

Comment: But to be clear: I very much appreciate that you take the time to digest all the feedback given to you. That is something that too many newbies dislike to do. They assume they can drop whatever content and that we just wait to do their work. My honest recommendation for you: consider deleting this question, to write up a new, better one.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Patricias answer seemed to help. Now we are progressing. Thanks for all the helpful feedback. I'll delete this thread.

Comment: @GhostCat either way, the problems about this question were that Zakan was trying to call a method from Result (with wrong syntax) in Event without creating an instance, and storing the results in a non-existing array. I'm not sure whether creating a new question will provide further help in solving it.

Comment: @Stultuske Keep in mind: the idea here is that questions are helpful for future readers. As of now, with zillions of comments, and that "missing" aspects of MCVE, that is not the case. So, there are only two things to do: A) delete this question ... and if the OP wants to, B) put up a better question.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know exactly the logic of your code but you can change the addResult method to something like this:

```
public void addResult(Participant partResult) {
    int participantIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
        Result result = resultList.get(i);
        if (result.getParticipant().getStartNumber() == partResult.getStartNumber()) {
            for (int a = 0; a < result.getResult().length; a++)
                result.getResult()[i] = result.getMaxAttempts();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at SportsCompetition.addResult(SportsCompetition.java:226)
 at SportsCompetition.commandLoop(SportsCompetition.java:42)
 at SportsCompetition.run(SportsCompetition.java:18)
 at SportsCompetition.main(SportsCompetition.java:13)

This is the error message I get from this.

Answer (score 0):

In your Event class, you do this:

```
result[i] = maxAttempts();
```

but in your Events class, you don't have an `maxAttempts` method. Either you need to add this method, or call it from the correct class/instance.

That answers this:

> maxAttempts is undefined for the type Event.

The other issue:

> result can not be solved to a variable.

You are trying to assign the result of that method as an element of an array called `result`, but there is no such array in your `Event` class, nor in your method as local variable.

EDIT

To call that method, first thing you need to do, is to create an instance of the class `Result`

```
Result example = new Result(0, 5, partResult);
```

When you've done that, you can call the get method on it:

```
example.getMaxResults();
```

Then you have your result. If you want to store it in an array, you'll need to create that array (or other variable) either local or on class level.

Either way, my recommendation is to stop doing what you're doing now. You're writing a whole lot of code you don't understand yourself.

First learn the basic principles of OO, it'll be a lot easier after.

Comment: Not. you nowhere have such a method. My best guess, you need to call the getMaxResults() method on an instance of your Result class

Comment: public int getMaxAttempts() {
     return maxAttempts;
    }
That is what I want to call from the Result class, yes. 
    result[i] = get.maxAttempts (?)

Or how do I write that correctly. Thanks